# Split up existing CSS files

Tags: css, npm, webpack, split

I'm new on a project where we are using .NET backend with Visual Studio and WebComplier to create CSS files out of SCSSs. It works fine, but it generates so huge CSS file (>8MB) so my task is to split this one file up into chunks, smaller than 1MB.
For example:

I have styles.css (8MB), I want to create

styles-1.css
styles-2.css
styles-4.css
...

There's no way to optimize this file, I have to deal with the big one.
I need help how to do that.
Is there a way to do it with

1. WebCompiler? OR
2. Webpack >4.1.1 OR
3. npm OR
4. any other solution?

Thanks for suggestions!

Comment: You can get extensions for some browsers to output a page's used CSS only, that could help. Mostly, though, if your CSS is that immense, this project is just being done incorrectly. There're probably lots of corner cases in it where someone has required a very specific visual when for hundreds of fewer lines you could have something almost exactly the same but via largely reused code. This happens a lot when someone wants a graphic design to be 100% translated into HTML/CSS, when instead you should almost always genericize it so this type of situation doesn't occur.

Comment: Yes, You're right, CSS is just messed up, but it's because it has been developed for so long that nobody knows the first developer that started the project, and there's many things are included. if I pull a string out nobody knows what could possibly go wrong. So I leave scss files as they are and try to split it up into chunks.

Comment: https://github.com/metalabdesign/css-split-webpack-plugin ?

Comment: @zak: I would start the slow process of replacing that terrible code, then. If you plan on being there for a while, anyway. <shrug>